# asp.net mvc 5 bootstrap 4 tamaño de tabla

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4, bootstrap

Me han pedido crear una aplicacion en asp.net la cual lleva varias tablas y para ponerlas mas modernas decidi instalarle bootstrap 4, el problema es que ahora las tablas no toman el tamaño total de la pantalla cuando antes con bootstrap 3 si lo hacian.
Alguna idea de lo que esta sucediendo???
Aqui esta una fotografia de lo que esta sucediendo:

https://ibb.co/FnVshw1

Mi codigo es este:

```
  table class="table table-bordered table-hover d-sm-table-cell table-sm table-responsive">
<tr class="bg-info">
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.codigoCargo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cargo)
    </th>
    <th>
        Accion
    </th>

</tr>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.codigoCargo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cargo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.codigoCargo }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.codigoCargo }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.codigoCargo })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: tu tabla la tienes dentro de algún contenedor? si es así puede que sea este el que está haciendo que no se vea más grande, por ejemplo un div que su clase sea **col-lg-6**?

Comment: otra cosa, probé con las clases que tienes y si le quitas **d-sm-table-cell**, **table-responsive** abarca toda la pantalla

Comment: wao men, muchisimas gracias, eso era todo lo que queria, muchas gracias